# How to search library in netbeans to find files that are of a certain type

Tags: java, netbeans

I need to search through the one of my drives on my computer to find all files of a certain format (wxs) so that I can read the file to check what there GUID is. How can I search for this?

Answer (score 2):

In NetBeans 8 - go to "Edit -> Find in Projects", you'll get a pop-up window like this:

[image: Find in Projects Pop-up]

You'll be able to search not only your projects - the "Scope" field will allow you to select a drive as well.